# How to detect single letters and modify their look/css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors

I want to scan a passage and have any single letters changed (***I*** have ***a*** dog that ate ***a*** chew toy)

A passage of text is placed in a textbox and then placed into a div. The modification can occur in either place I assume but I have had some trouble manipulating text in the div so far.

I am, however only able to use jquery/javascript/css/html because that's all I understand sadly.

Please explain the answer also as I often don't quite get the more complex of your answers but as always,

THANKS for ANSWERING!

Comment: can you please show what have you tried

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/clarinetking/6cLgghme/15/
Look at the singles jquery script

Comment: What trouble did you have? Please post the code you tried in your question.

Comment: @clarinetking can you explain the purpose of last two textareas ?

Comment: I am on the IOS version now as I have had to go out of the ICT room :/ I will post the code as soon as I get home :) I tried jquery with a function that detects whether or not a word is present then changes the CSS but it changed everything in the div

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LL5hkcoc/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this using **[replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)**

```
$('div.text').html(function(i,v){
   return v.replace(/(^|\s[A-Za-z]\s|$)/g,'<b>$&</b>');
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/LL5hkcoc/2/)

Comment: You regexp can be much shorter: `/(^|\s[A-Za-z]\s|$)/g`. [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LL5hkcoc/2/).

Comment: Thank you very much! Please could you explain how regexp works? I read the page but don't understand the part inside the bold tag and the g in the preceding area

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp?_e_pi_=7%2CPAGE_ID10%2C5514895045

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Answer (score 1):

You cand achive it with a regular expresion:

```
var text = "I have a dog that ate a chew toy";
text= " " + text + " ";
var matches = text.match(/\s\w\s/);
```

Explanation: you look this pattern: [space][letter][space], in concrete the case of first and last letter you don't have the first or last space, that's why I put two extra spaces on the text.

Comment: `\w` also matches `0-9` and `_`. `\s` doesn't handle situations: beginning of string, end of string.